# Hide characters in HTML?

Tags: css, html, django-templates

I am writing an application in Django and i have to show some information and hide some like if contact number is "9087654321" then i want to show this like "908*****21". I don't know java script. So how can i do it only with HTML and CSS.I am a newbie so please be generous and easy. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: So you want to show only first 3 and last 2 characters?

Comment: yeah and i would also like to do this with other sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are two ways to deal with that- first one is one, which was presented by Erik Kralj- use Javascript.

Second one is use Python to do so. You can write a method in your view, which will hide this sensitive data for user, which is not logged in etc.

Then just use in Python:

```
no = list(no)
no[3:-2] = "*" * len(no[3:-2])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i chose this approach.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var str = "9087654321";
str.slice(0,3) + str.slice(3,-2).replace(/./g,'*') + str.slice(-2);
// "908*****21"
```

Works with every contact number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var contactNumber = "9087654321";
var maskedNumber = contactNumber.substr(0, 3) + Array(contactNumber.length - 4).join('*') + contactNumber.substr(contactNumber.length - 2, 2);
```

Takes the first 3 and last 2 numbers and fills the gap with stars(asterisk).

Result of `maskedNumber` would be `908*****21`

For security reasons ***I would recommend [PatNowak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590695/381802)*** as it hides the contact number before it is sent to the client.